# how to automatically deduct and add value from the output?

Tags: python

I am making a program of basic automatic computation for math. I am having a problem of automatically deducting the sch to get the qualified output of the percentage.

```
total = float(input("input price: "))
mgr = total * 0.6
sch = total * 0.4

if mgr < 1350:
   mgr = 1350
   scho = sch - mgr
   print(mgr)
   print(scho)
```

for example, the input would be, 2000. the output should be automatically:

```
mgr = 1350
scho = 650
```

the scho is automatically deducted to add value for the mgr to make it 1350 automatically if it is < 1350

Comment: Please explain, what are `sch`, `mgr` and `scho` ? What is your problem? What do you expect, and what was the output/error ?

Comment: they are just variables that i used, and i don't have an error.

Comment: Do you mean `scho = total - mgr`?

Comment: based on my example, my input is 2000, since the 60% of the mgr is only 1200, it will meet the condition, if mgr < 1350, the mgr value would be 1350 but, it will deduct from the sch, for how many value was added to make the mgr to 1350.

Comment: Im not sure if I understood you correctly, but I think you could simply find the difference between 1350 and mgr and then add the difference to mgr and subtract the difference from scho

Comment: Do you only want to (a) calc `scho` and (b) print if `mgr < 1350` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `scho` should represent, but according to your description, you only need to calculate `mgr` first, then subtract from the total:

```
total = float(input("input price: "))
mgr = total * 0.6
#sch = total * 0.4  # this is not used

if mgr < 1350:
    mgr = 1350
    scho = int(total - mgr)
    print(mgr)
    print(scho)
```

output:

```
input price: 2000
1350
650
```

Comment: you got it right thank you!